# Override displayed text in Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown when value is zero

Tags: winforms

I have a Windows Forms project with a NumericUpDown control in it.

The meaning of one of the fields is such that 0 (or null) means unlimited and so I want to display this instead of 0.

How do you get the NumericUpDown control to display "Unlimited" instead of "0"

Comment: In WPF this could be doable (of course WPF does not come with a NumericUpDown out of the box), I am not sure you can do this kind of overriding with WinForms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible by overriding the [UpdateEditText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.updateedittext.aspx) method:

```
public class CustomNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    public CustomNumericUpDown()
    {
    }

    protected override void UpdateEditText()
    {
        // Custom display-value when value is 0
        this.Text = this.Value == 0 ? "unlimited" : this.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

This will now print "unlimited":

```
        var n = new CustomNumericUpDown();
        n.Value = 0;

        MessageBox.Show(n.Text);
```

Comment: Nice.  Id' consider using `0 - Unlimited` myself.

Comment: Sorry about the slow acceptance. I had other projects distracting me. Just tried this now and that was exactly what I was after; thank you.